# Converting string to date fails with exception - unparsable date even though format is correct

Tags: android, kotlin

Error:

```
W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Jul 20 2020 17:21:02"
```

Code:

```
fun getDate(): Long {
    var dateInMillis = 0L
    var date: Date? = null

    try {
        val stringDate = "Jul 20 2020 17:21:02"
        date = SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(stringDate)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    date?.let {
        dateInMillis = it.time
    }

    return dateInMillis
}
```

Format looks correct, but I still get Unparseable date error. Any ideas?

Comment: I just copy/pasted your code and it works fine, maybe share your imports as well? I would also suggest not having 01/01/1970 as your `getDate` fallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Locale` with `SimpleDateFormat`, since you are not it creates with the default.

for example:

```
SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss",Locale.US).parse(stringDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code down below.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

fun main() {
    val str =  "Jul 20 2020 17:21:02";
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    val dt = LocalDateTime.parse(str,formatter);

    println(dt.toString())
}
```